# Button doesn't trigger the corresponding action (both tag button and input type=button)

Tags: javascript, jquery, button, internet-explorer-8, popup

My jquery code works with Chrome, Firefox, > IE8, but it seems that jquery and jquery ui aren't loaded on IE8.

Javascript is enabled.

I use `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=7,IE=8" />`, 'cause I had some issues on IE9

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=7,IE=8" />
<link href="css/my.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.js"></script>
<link href="css/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<script type="text/javascript">
         $(function(){
         }); // Sorry, really it's so and not only }
</script>
</head>
```

Any suggestion? What I should check?

**EDIT**

By changing

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=7,IE=8" />
```

to

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8" />
```

resolves most of the issues on IE8.

The only issue still remains is tied to pop up:

when there is a button which triggers a pop up, clicking on pop up "OK" doesn't trigger the corresponding action (the button is inside an a tag).

Comment: Shouldn't it be `$(function(){ //code here });` or `(function($){})(jQuery);`?

Comment: "aren't loaded on IE8" - why aren't they loaded? Is there some errors in the Javascript console?

Comment: don't forget to accept the correct answer by clicking on the check mark at the top-left of the answer

Comment: so.... is this still an issue? did fixing the typo fix the problem? Looking at your code, i see no reason that it wouldn't work in IE8.

Comment: What makes you think that `jQuery` is not loaded ? If your script doesn't work, there could be other issues as well.

Comment: @KevinB: It was already `$(function(){});`. I made a typo error here on stackoverflow. As I wrote, the code works on Chrome, Firefox, > IE8, but not on <=IE8. Javascript is enabled on the browser. So, I don't know what to check.

Comment: Why doesn't it work? How does it not work? What does "not work" mean? How much of the code gets executed? where does it stop?

Comment: @SheikhHeera: hide, show, tooltip, datepicker, nothing work.

Comment: Check `$(function(){ alert(typeof jQuery) });` if it alerts `undefined`.

Comment: the problem is not with the code you have provided thus far.

Comment: If you have an error in your script nothing should work but it doesn't mean that `jQuery` is not loaded.

Comment: @SheikhHeera: all the part tied to jquery don't work. I'll try your code.

Comment: Also you can debug in `IE8` by pressing `f12`, [check How to use F12 Developer Tools to Debug your Webpages, if needed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg589507(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: Have you set the type="text/javascript" in the script include of jQuery and jQuery UI?

Comment: @Edward: Yes, I always put my jquery code in `<script type="text/javascript"></script>`

Comment: @Cricket please provide more code to enhance this question. **"clicking on pop up "OK" doesn't trigger the corresponding action (the button is inside an a tag)."** - where is the popup? where is the code for that "OK" button? This question is still not clear. How will people answer this then? no offence meant :)

Answer (score 3):

Did you try this?

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8,IE=EDGE" />
```

Comment: What's the meaning of IE=EDGE?

Comment: Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14611264/x-ua-compatible-content-ie-9-ie-8-ie-7-ie-edge

Answer (score 0):

Could you put it in a jQuery.Ready function and see if it works more consistently between browsers? I see the comments suggested the same thing using a different format:

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=7,IE=8" />
<link href="css/my.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.js"></script>
<link href="css/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<script type="text/javascript">
         $(document).ready(function(){
            // do something here...
         }); // Sorry, really it's so and not only }
</script>
</head>
```

..

Also suggest updating your jquery, jquery-ui and jquery-ui css and jquery validation to the latest versions.  You should be able to use modernizr javascript library to detect which version of browser you have and then apply those meta tags to suit your needs.

This [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh394148.aspx) will detect which version of browser you have using modernizr.