# Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'kendoWindow' in Telerik Reporting in IE only

Tags: internet-explorer, telerik, reporting

0x800a01b6 - Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'kendoWindow'

Following error is coming only in IE 9 while in Chrome and Firefox it is working fine.

While telerik Reporting i am getting this error please see the attached file as well.
![enter image description here][1]

Answer (score 1):

This message may be caused by Internet Explorer entering in a compatibility mode, this may be casued by many things that go by the use of an incorrect Doctype tag to a configuration on Internet Explorer itself, what you can do to try this is to open the Developer Tools (Press F12) and in Explorer Mode select the highest available (IE9 in your case) and on Document Mode select Standard (also you can play with several modes), once you find one that works, you may want to add a Meta tag to force this particular mode like this: ["X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9; IE=8; IE=7; IE=EDGE"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14611264/x-ua-compatible-content-ie-9-ie-8-ie-7-ie-edge)