# IE8 nav li stays in div

Tags: css, menu

I have a menu that works fine in all browsers except for... IE8 and IE9.

When I scroll the menu it should pop out (what it does fine in all other browsers) but in IE it 'stays inside the div' so it's not overlapping.

In the example below you can see how the menu stays in the div and the searchbar below is overlapping.

PS:
I've tried al sorts of things with z-index, but it wil not work...

[image: example]

Comment: You give us a problem, but there is no code?

Comment: Please post CSS/HTML or a link to the page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trying adding the following lines to the code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9" />
```

Comment: It makes IE understand the code and makes it browser compatible to specified version. For more details refer to this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14611264/x-ua-compatible-content-ie-9-ie-8-ie-7-ie-edge

Comment: O sorry, this was the answer. But I still don't really understand how a older browser understands a newer browser...