# IE=edge Compatible is not working

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, browser, compatibility

I set

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
```

in my web application. 
But After page loading , open developer tool ,it  shows ie7 doc mode and browser mode in IE8 browser that i set before page load.
Its not rendering in latest document mode.
I need some code that open my website in latest document mode in IE.
How can i do this?

Comment: Try this, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14611264/x-ua-compatible-content-ie-9-ie-8-ie-7-ie-edge

Answer (score 0):

It may be cause by conditional comments surrounding the HTML tag.
It can be solved by adding the right header in the .htaccess file, like this:

```
BrowserMatch MSIE ie
Header set X-UA-Compatible "IE=Edge,chrome=1" env=i
```

For more information read this issue: https://github.com/h5bp/html5-boilerplate/issues/378