# Treat callback response in $.ajax() as JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, jquery-callback

I have:

```
<script>
    $('#email').on('blur', function(){
        email = $(tihs).val();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "ajax.php",
            data: {
                'email': email,
                'job': 'check',
            },
            dataType: "JSON",
            success: function (response) {
                // the response from PHP is smth like:
                // {"status":"failed","reason":"email_not_validated"}
                // now I want to:
                if(response.status == 'success'){

                }else{

                }
            }   
        })
    });
</script>
```

This seems to work on every browser **except IE**, why is that?

Am I doing the right thing? the only thing which I need is to access the returned data like `response.status` and `response.reason` .

Thanks for helping

Comment: Error here `email = $(tihs).val();`. Also `email` is leaking to the global scope.

Comment: what is happening in IE and what is the jQuery version used

Comment: What version of IE are you using.

Comment: @TAS IE 10, I tested with some alerts, it seems the job value is not being sent, I receive "no job sent"

Comment: @elclanrs that was mistyped here, it's ok in my source, edited by the way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a mentioned [IE10 bug](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/12790) that can be fixed [by adding](http://code.gishan.net/code/solution-to-ie10-ajax-problem/)

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE9" />
```

in the `<head>`. Note in a `<head>` there should not be another meta tags with `X-UA-Compatible` as the previous one will be overridden.

Comment: is it gonna work also on OLD IEs? I'm using jQuery 1.11 with Bootstrap 3

Comment: sure, it will work even with IE6 including any *stable* version of jquery

Comment: No it won't work as far as trailing comma is concerned, you can test it for sure.

Comment: @Jai I believe you're wrong, trailing commas never cause errors, and I'm just seeing it working WITH the comma... .

Comment: @behz4d He's right - that misleading comma could cause syntax error in outdated browsers. So the best thing here you can do is remove it after `'job': 'check',`. Anyway you have nothing to loose.

Comment: in IE i seen this kind of issues because of commas

Comment: @djay still the 'job' is not being sent in IE 10 :-(, I have also removed the comma

Comment: @behz4d Try `print_r($_POST)` (for testing purposes) in your php script when running IE10. What does it return?

Comment: @djay how should be the PHP side with this? I'm doing with `if(isset($_POST['job'])){..}else{ echo "nojob"; }`

Comment: with print_r($_POST): in Mozilla I get: `Array
(
    [email] => dsadsaddasd
    [job] => check
)`

Comment: in IE I get an empty array Array ()

Comment: @behz4d Well seems like a solution to this would be adding `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE9" >` in the `<head>`

Comment: @behz4d As for an explanation, take a look at this: http://code.gishan.net/code/solution-to-ie10-ajax-problem/

Comment: WTF IE's doing alive?

Comment: @djay I had `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">`, I removed it and placed with `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE9" >`, now it's working fine, what was the thing I removed? `content="IE=edge"`

Comment: @behz4d Yeah exactly. This is because it was overridden. Look, you had `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible"` (the same key).

Comment: @behz4d An explanation of `IE=edge` is here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14611323/1208233

Comment: Yup I read that earlier, but since I'm on Bootstrap 3, removing that and replacing it with the new one is gonna work for responsiveness? and please update your answer so I could accept it. ty

Comment: @behz4d Since the tags/values that agents do not understand will be ignored, I'd assume that this should work for responsiveness too.

Comment: @djay mistyped, ty anyway