# GWT tool is not loading in IE8 when IE8 emulates IE9

Tags: gwt, internet-explorer-8, gwt2, sakai

I am using Gradebook2 for Sakai, developed using GWT. This tool is not loading in IE8 (without compatibility view) when I set the property sakai.X-UA-Compatible=IE=EmulateIE9.

When I enable compatibility view this tool is loading properly even though I set the property sakai.X-UA-Compatible=IE=EmulateIE9

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible, for some reason that having **IE=EmulateIE9** alone is getting IE8 to fall back to the wrong setting. That's not unusual as [described here](http://emological.com/ie/).

Maybe you need something like

```
sakai.X-UA-Compatible=IE=9; IE=8; IE=7
```

as mentioned on this [related article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14611264/x-ua-compatible-content-ie-9-ie-8-ie-7-ie-edge).

I think that having **edge** would work but the you probably also want IE10 and IE11 to fallback to IE9 compatibility mode as then you might see other issues in those browsers.