# What is the difference between content="IE=7; IE=9" and content="IE=7, IE=9"

Tags: javascript, html, css, meta

On my HTML, have used the meta tag as below for some font issues. I just want to know:

Are these both meta tag meaning the same? Or each one is different?

`<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=7, IE=9" />` [separated by comma]

`<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=7; IE=9" />`  [separated by semicolon]

Please explain on this.

Comment: possible duplicate of ["X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9; IE=8; IE=7; IE=EDGE"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14611264/x-ua-compatible-content-ie-9-ie-8-ie-7-ie-edge)

Comment: no they dont, check the link in my other comment

Comment: @FelixLahmer: although that linked question seems to ask about the difference between semi-colons and commas it doesn't actually seem to address that part anywhere that I can see...

Comment: @chris If you separate with semi-colon, it sets compatibility levels for different versions if not, 1 compatibility level gets applied, thats what the accepted answer says

Comment: @FelixLahmer: it is very explicit about what a semi colon means but to my reading doesn't explain what exactly `content="IE=7, IE=9"` would do. ie is that just a syntax error? will it do something useful or totally unexpected?

Comment: @chris when using a semicolon u get different compatible modes, when using a , there is only one

Comment: @FelixLahmer: Is it advisable to use content="IE7; IE9"? Will this not break any content on browser such as graphics, fonts or images? Please.

Comment: it will render ie7 and ie8 in ie7  mode and ie9 as ie 9, the meta itself doesnt break anything, depends on your content

Answer (score -1):

The correct form, as **Microsoft** defines in **MSDN** is using a semicolong instead of a single comma:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=7, IE=9" />
```

Here the piece of text:

> Note: [...] You can also use the content attribute to specify multiple
>   document compatibility modes; this helps to ensure that web pages
>   display consistently in future versions of the browser. To specify
>   multiple document modes, set the content attribute to identify such
>   modes to use. Use a sign semicolon to separate the modes together.

[MSDN Resource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/cc288325(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: this is incorrect,  if you separate with semi-colon, it sets compatibility levels for different versions.

Comment: you say is using a semicolon but provide another example, do you even know what u talk about?