# Download file per ashx in new window, different behavior in IE9 and IE11

Tags: html, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11

I'm having a form in my page. This form is using post as method and an ashx to generate download content. Target is "_blank".

```
<form method='post' action='myHandler.ashx' id='myForm' target='_blank'>
```

Additionaly the form has some fields to parse parameters to the ashx.
But the download is not the problem. It is working fine. The problems is the behavior of IE.
In Firefox and IE9 the behavior is as wanted: new window pops up and gets closed after the download is prepared (browser native download dialog shown in the original window).
In IE11 the new window does not get closed anymore...
Is there something I can do to get the same behavior in IE11 as in Firefox and IE9?
Or at least any hint what the problem maybe can be?

Greetings

EDIT:
For now I have solved it by using an hidden iFrame in the page as target for the form. So there is no new window at all. But is there a common way or best practice how such downloads should to be done?

Answer (score 0):

One option could be to force IE9 (standards) in a meta tag - I believe that would work:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9" />
```

and more info on this here:  ["X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9; IE=8; IE=7; IE=EDGE"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14611264/x-ua-compatible-content-ie-9-ie-8-ie-7-ie-edge)

Comment: When i Change the browsermode to IE9 I'm getting the same beavior =(