# internet explorer 11 not loading stylesheet

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, internet-explorer

This is my `<head>` section that is loading my CSS files without problem on FF and chrome.

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"><meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8,9,10,11">

<meta name="description" content="">

<link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://www.es-processing.com/static/images/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">

<script src="index_files/core.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>$(function() {
   $('#slideshow_1').cycle({
        fx: 'scrollHorz',       
        easing: 'easeInOutCirc',
        speed:  1100, 
        timeout: 6000, 
        pager: '.ss1_wrapper .slideshow_paging', 
        prev: '.ss1_wrapper .slideshow_prev',
        next: '.ss1_wrapper .slideshow_next',
        // using the "before" function, we grab the content of the active slide and show it in our custom box overlay
        before: function(currSlideElement, nextSlideElement) {
            var data = $('.data', $(nextSlideElement)).html();
            $('.ss1_wrapper .slideshow_box .data').fadeOut(300, function(){
                $('.ss1_wrapper .slideshow_box .data').remove();
                $('<div class="data">'+data+'</div>').hide().appendTo('.ss1_wrapper .slideshow_box').fadeIn(600);
            });
        }
    });

    // not using the 'pause' option. instead make the slideshow pause when the mouse is over the whole wrapper
    $('.ss1_wrapper').mouseenter(function(){
        $('#slideshow_1').cycle('pause');
    }).mouseleave(function(){
        $('#slideshow_1').cycle('resume');
    });

});</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="index_files/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="index_files/generic.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
var slideInterval=20000;
var slideTransition=3500;
var slideArray=["index_files/background1.jpg","index_files/background2.jpg","index_files/background3.jpg"];
jQuery.fx.interval=33;
// -->
</script>
<link href="index_files/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="index_files/16204.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
```

The "main.css" isn't loading at all in IE although in previous version of my website it worked fine. However, if i edit the line

```
<link href="index_files/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

in IE11 developper tool, and rewrite "main.css" and pressed enter, my page will be styled again in IE. Is there a way to force IE to execute the "main.css" line?

Comment: Is your `16204.css` loaded?

Comment: if it only fails in IE, it might be related to your `X-UA-Compatible` statement. please refer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14611264/1325979).

Comment: @lolka_bolka in the "network" tab, i can see that both CSS are loaded, but the styling isn't applying.

Comment: check your CSS for any syntax errors. IE sometimes ignore css after error. Try debugging with putting only some css code in file.

Comment: Is this `http://es-processing.com/index.htm` the page in question?

Comment: @ted yes it is indeed

Comment: fwiw, I'm not seeing any obvious difference between Chrome and IE11. I am seeing js and missing resource errors though (not for the css). Simple things I would try first would be testing without the previously mentioned meta tag (it may not be formatted correctly), and moving the css links above the script tags.

Comment: @ted i tried moving it before the script tag, but the onlinne version is actually an older version that was ok on explorer. Now, when i inlcuded the generic.js for a background slider, the CSS won't render anymore in explorer. But i don't think there's a relationship.

Comment: @user3340234 It appears to be loading for me: http://i.imgur.com/Wm6VDsO.png.

Comment: @jonathanSampson I tested the new version online, and it seems it's woorking too. But why offline doesn't work? this is weird.

Comment: @user3340234 By *offline* do you mean *localhost*? What do you see in the Network tab of the Developer Tools when you're testing locally?