# Make "IE9 Compatibility View" mode default when IE9 renders a site

Tags: html, internet-explorer-9, meta-tags

I have developed a web site on Google App Engine using JSP and JQuery 1.11.2. The following  tag is added to the Head section on every jsp.

`<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />`

The client has to be using IE9 to view this site. Also, the javascript code only works with "IE9 Compatibility View".

The issue is every time the user opens the home page IE9 renders it in "Internet Explorer 9" mode instead of ""IE9 Compatibility View"".

How can I set up the `meta` tag in `head` to force IE9 to use "IE9 Compatibility View" as Browser Mode and keep "IE9 Standards" as Document Mode?

Answer (score 0):

For force IE9 to use "IE9 Compatibility View", like this:

```
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
```

or use `X-UA-Compatible` in the `HTTP header`.

Comment: What is the difference between the two lines? Are they equivalent to each other?

Comment: please refer  this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14611264/x-ua-compatible-content-ie-9-ie-8-ie-7-ie-edge

Answer (score -1):

Use this as a first meta tag in page,

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
```