# About X-UA-Compatibility version

Tags: internet-explorer, google-chrome-frame

Is it okay to use something like this:

```
<META http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=7; IE=Emulate8; IE=9; IE=Edge; Chrome=1">
```

Or this:

```
<META http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=7; IE=Emulate8; IE=9; IE=Edge, Chrome=1">
```

Or either of these two will suffice?

```
<META http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge, Chrome=1">
<META http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge; Chrome=1">
```

I don't know which version is best to use? The one with "IE=Edge, Chrome=1/IE=Edge; Chrome=1" or the other two?

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9; IE=8; IE=7; IE=EDGE"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14611264/x-ua-compatible-content-ie-9-ie-8-ie-7-ie-edge)

Comment: Anyhow, unless you want to make newer versions of IE behave like older versions, use `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge, Chrome=1">` BTW, this question doesn't have anything to with with Firefox or Chrome, but IE and Chrome-Frame.

Comment: Thanks for explanation and thanks for correcting/editing.