# IFrame rendered differently on IE9 and IE11

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, asp.net-mvc, iframe

I have created a traditional file upload using form and iframe. My html:

```
<form id="theuploadform">
    <div class="form-group">
        <input id="importFile" name="file" size="50" type="file" />
    </div>
</form>
```

The javascript:

```
var iframe = $('<frame name="postiframe" id="postiframe" style="display: none"></frame>');
$("body").append(iframe);
var form = $('#theuploadform');
form.attr("action", "/uploadhandler.ashx");
form.attr("method", "post");

form.attr("encoding", "multipart/form-data");
form.attr("enctype", "multipart/form-data");

form.attr("target", "postiframe");
form.attr("file", $('#userfile').val());
form.submit();
```

Now it will post to `UploadHandler.ashx` that will write the contents of the file to the iframe:

```
context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
context.Response.Write(new StreamReader(file.InputStream).ReadToEnd());
```

My problem here is that the iframe content is being rendered different on ie9 and ie11.

IE11:

```
<iframe>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<body>
<pre>
// xml content here //
</pre>
```

IE9:

```
<iframe>
<Nodename xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
```

Any thoughts to make the iframe same as on IE11?

**EDIT**

I have the following code on my `_Layout.cshtml`:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge,chrome=1" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding a meta tag for IE:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge" />
```

It forces the browser the render at whatever the most recent version's standards are. Just like using the latest version of jQuery on Google's CDN, this is the most recent, but also can potentially break your code since its not a fixed version.

or you could be more specific with `IE9`:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE9" />
```

or

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=IE9" />
```

Checkout a detailed answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14611323/1059101).

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I updated my question, unfortunately I already have this meta code on my `_Layout.cshtml`

Comment: is it the file which is loaded in the iframe?

Comment: My iframe is located on a file, say for example `File.cshtml`. This file is being rendered on the `_Layout.cshtml` by using the `RenderBody()` so I think it should be okay?

Comment: I did some research, turns out that I also need to specify the meta tag on the view even though it is already present on the `_Layout.cshtml`. Thank you for the idea!