# Cross session issues occurring when running multiple pages of application in different tabs

Tags: c#, .net, internet-explorer

I am working on a .net application and when i run it in ie it opens up in ie 5 by default(I can see that on doing inspect element ) and i'm unable to find where has this been actually assigned .
How can i change this default version of ie?
I need to move to ie 7 or more as there are some cross - session problem occurring in my application when multiple pages on different tabs are opened simultaneously. Thanks in Advance !

Comment: `Microsoft Internet Explorer 5 (IE5) is a graphical web browser ... It is included with Windows 98 SE and Windows ME and it is the last version of Internet Explorer for Windows 3.1x, Windows NT 3.x and Windows 95. ` Are you sure?

Comment: It's because you're using meta tag with version of **IE5**, more information can be found here

[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14611264/x-ua-compatible-content-ie-9-ie-8-ie-7-ie-edge)