# Browser Mode in IE11

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11

I see an answer suggested in the link : [Registry Hack For IE11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17871124/how-to-bring-back-browser-mode-in-ie11/17934862#17934862)

The instructions say save as .reg and run.

Can anyone specify how to save the registry values as re and how to run the same as I've never run this sort of document before.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't do this. This hack was never supported, doesn't work, and isn't necessary. An update to IE11 late last year added the document modes back to the Emulation tab of the F12 Developer tools.

Comment: I want one of my website to run as IE8 browser and in Quirks mode.That's the reason I was trying for this hack. Is there any way to get `IE8 browser mode and in Quirks mode in IE11`.

Comment: The dropdowns in the Emulation tab are the right thing to use. However, if you're really trying to test IE8, the right way to do it is to use one of the free VMs from http://modern.ie/

Comment: Can you point out where is the "Quirks Mode" setting. I can set the Document Mode as 8 but cannot find the Quirks Mode setting. The reason I'm trying for this is to get my legacy website to run on IE11 which is creating issues.

Comment: Quirks Mode is also known as `IE5`. But rather than messing with this, why not share your site's URL and get help on getting it compatible with modern standards used by IE and all other major browsers?

Comment: I selected that too but did not work. The earlier setting we used to use on IE10 was IE8 in Quirks mode. Is there any similar setting which would match that. BTW we are in the process of upgrading the site to run on modern browsers but for the users already migrated to IE11 I'm trying to find a quick fix. Any suggestions.

Comment: You change the `User-Agent string` dropdown to send the IE8 User-Agent string, but this obviously isn't something you can expect your users to do.

Comment: So should the User-Agent string be IE8 and Browser mode be IE5 to simulate the old setting.