# SVG text path not working correctly in IE

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg, d3.js

I am making an SVG which has text along a circular line path.

The text looks great in Firefox and Chrome, but doesn't look right in IE11. Only the first letter on the text path appears, sometimes.

Here's [the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f7vwq/1/).

```
     d3.select("#svg")
.append("path")
  .attr("id", "path1")
  .attr("d", "M 0,-1   C 0.5523, -1   1, -0.5523    1,0  C 1, 0.5523    0.5523, 1     0,1  C -0.5523, 1   -1, 0.5523    -1,0         C -1, -0.5523  -0.5523, -1   0,-1")
  .attr("transform", "scale(50, 50) translate(5,5)");


  d3.select("#svg")
  .append("text")
  .append("textPath")
  .attr("xlink:href", "#path1")
  .style("font-size", "10px")
  .text("hello radial world")
  .attr("fill", "blue")
```

Comment: Are you sure that the browser mode and document mode are set to IE 8+?

Comment: I am not sure. Is that done by setting the doctype?

Comment: check this discussion: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17871124/how-to-bring-back-browser-mode-in-ie11, make sure you set at least IE 9, because IE8 does not support SVG.

Comment: CSS file uses `-webkit-` rules.

Comment: It is not entirely clear to me how much to blame IE for this. Check this [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/jr2z6/) in **IE11**. Looks like something in your path instructions is causing some trouble.

Comment: Yes, it is the path. I have been working on it but I can't find one that will work in all browsers and display the text on the outside of the circular path. If you had one, I would give the bounty.

Comment: This [example](http://bl.ocks.org/musically-ut/5278601) is the closest thing I've seen.

Comment: @FernOfTheAndes that is close but as the question stated the text needs to appear on the outside of the circle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up figuring this out.

Here is the winning formula for text on the outside of a circular path in SVG that's compatible with IE, Firefox AND Chrome!

```
var size = 50; // radius of ring
var centerX = 100;  // center x
var centerY = 100;  // center y

d3.select("#myDiv")
  .append("path")
.attr("id", "path1")
  .attr("d", "m "+centerX+", "+centerY+" a -"+size+",-"+size+" 1 1,1 "+size*2+",0 a -"+size+",-"+size+" 1 1,1 -"+size*2+",0")
 // do not use transform scale with text paths, IE does not like it! Define variables like this.

  d3.select("#myDiv")
    .append("text")
    .append("textPath")
    .attr("xlink:href", "#path1")
    .style("font-size", "10px")
    .style('letter-spacing','0px')
    .text("hello radial world")
    .attr("fill", "blue")
```

Comment: Thanks. Exactly what I needed. Saved me from figuring it out myself.

Answer (score 1):

some of the problems you are having are due to you including an extra comma in your array declarations, such as on line 151 in your html page:

```
var options = [{
    name: "Casting",
    link: "casting",
    color: "#737373",
}, {...
```

The extra comma after the last array item 'color: "#737373",' is invalid Javascript syntax (ECMA3) and will upset many browsers.

Please see the answer to this question:

[Are trailing commas in arrays and objects part of the spec?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7246618/trailing-commas-in-javascript)

It looks like you have similar errors in Home.js and magic.circles.js. Trailing commas like this are legal in some other languages, but not Javascript. Firefox/Chrome/Safari seem to be tolerant of the error, but most versions of IE will choke on it.

This site has a handy tool to find your rogue commas:

http://trailingcomma.com/

Comment: Hey Underscore. 

Thanks for the answer. I removed the trailing commas from the page but the error persists.

Best regards,,
DS

Comment: Hey Boat, could you put a jsFiddle up for magicCircles? Your page has a lot of dependencies and I can't reproduce it locally. Besides I want to play with the circles :-)