# JavaScript/jQuery stopped functioning in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

I have the following script:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(this).find("[id$='Panel']").hide();
        $(".toggleDisplay").change(function () {
            var groupName = $(this).find(":radio").attr('name');
            var ans = $('input[name="' + groupName + '"]:radio:checked').val();
            var displaylist = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"];
            if (displaylist.indexOf(ans) > -1) {
                $(this).find("[id$='Panel']").show();
            } else {
                $(this).find("[id$='Panel']").hide();
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

When I inserted/tested this last week, it worked fine in IE 11. Today, it stopped working. However, it still works in Chrome. The IE error I receive is: "Object doesn't support property or method 'indexOf'"

I attempted to rewrite the if statement as follows, with no luck:

```
if ($.inArray(ans, displayList) != -1) {}
```

Any suggestions?

EDIT: The issue was my browser (somehow) reverting back to rendering as IE 8. Seems that this is a company wide issue. To prevent further hiccups, is there a painless method of doing this script in IE 8-compatible code?

Comment: Are u testing in the same IE11? If so - did DOCTYPE of the document changed? Or some meta tags to emulate older IE added?

Comment: Yes, and no. Literally, nothing changed in the document between Friday's functional run & today's.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A plausible guess is that you've somehow bumped your version of IE to emulate IE8, which doesn't support `indexOf()` (see [Why doesn't indexOf work on an array IE8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3629183/why-doesnt-indexof-work-on-an-array-ie8)). You can do this (accidentally or otherwise) in various ways - see this answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17877416/68231.

Comment: Frick. I have no idea how, but this is what it was. Thanks.

Comment: The weirdest part is, I have no idea how it worked last week, but not today. I haven't reset my browser, and our header had <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8" > tucked in it.