# PreSendRequestHeaders alternative in a HttpModule

Tags: c#, asp.net, httpmodule

According to this information given by the Asp.Net team [What not to do in Asp.net](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/aspnet/overview/web-development-best-practices/what-not-to-do-in-aspnet-and-what-to-do-instead#presend) you should not use `PreSendRequestHeaders` in a managed HttpModule.

> PreSendRequestHeaders and PreSendRequestContext
>
> Recommendation: Do not use these events with managed modules.
>
> The PreSendRequestHeaders and PreSendRequestContext events can be used
> with native IIS modules, but not with managed modules that implement
> IHttpModule. Setting these properties can cause issues with
> asynchronous requests.

This is precisely what I do in my [Image Processing Library](https://github.com/JimBobSquarePants/ImageProcessor/blob/master/src/ImageProcessor.Web/NET45/HttpModules/ImageProcessingModule.cs#L143) to ensure that the correct mime type is sent along with the response.

What would be the recommended alternative approach?

Comment: https://github.com/JimBobSquarePants/ImageProcessor/blob/master/src/ImageProcessor.Web/NET45/HttpModules/ImageProcessingModule.cs#L143 not found

Comment: Should have used the absolute link. Code is long gone now using `PostReleaseRequestState` instead.
https://github.com/JimBobSquarePants/ImageProcessor/blob/c36a37d250432a6e93bc4b1a04410ddc2e193c02/src/ImageProcessor.Web/HttpModules/ImageProcessingModule.cs#L328

Answer (score 5):

In a handler for `BeginRequest`, use [`HttpResponse.AddOnSendingHeaders`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.addonsendingheaders(v=vs.110).aspx) to subscribe a handler for that event.

This is essentially the same thing as `PreSendRequestHeaders`, however it is handled fully within the ASP.NET pipeline so it doesn't have the same problems with the native/managed interface that `PreSendRequestHeaders` does.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the `HttpApplication` pipeline on [MSDN's ASP.NET App Life Cycle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb470252.aspx#Stages) page you'll find `PreSendRequestHeaders` and `PreSendRequestContent` events at the very bottom. Now that they're suggesting we not use these in managed `IHttpModule`s, the next closest event in the pipeline would be `EndRequest`, which is deterministic unlike PreSendRequest* events.

I haven't been able to find any information on what the preferred practice is now for specifying response headers, but this will work for you.

Comment: Too bad, this won't work. `EndRequest` is too late, it will result in an exception. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7198205/exception-thrown-in-end-request-when-adding-headers